# Android: How do I make the ActionBar.OnNavigationListener being called for every item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my app, I want to use an ActionBar Spinner for navigation, although I know that this is not really the purpose of the Spinner. My problem is, that the first item in the Menu list is selected automatically when the Activity is started and a click on this first item doesn't trigger the Listener, as long as the first item is "active". What is the best and least hacky way to implement a fully working navigation menu looking exactly the same as the Spinner menu of the Actionbar? (i.e. with this small arrow on the bottom right etc.)